# Binary search in file by index

Tags: php

Im trying to make a script to get information in a file. The data in the file has this format:

```
 #index|info1|info2|info3|info4|#index2|info21|info22|info23|info24
```

So I have to make a binary search direct on the file, look for the index and get all its information. For example:

```
 $index = "index2";
 Output: index2 info21 info22 info24
```

I tried:

```
 $file = "file.txt";     
    // open the file for reading
 $myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("File cannot be openned");

$indexToSearch = "9780857293039";

$begging = 0;    
$end = filesize($file) / sizeof($indexToSearch) - 1;    

while($begging <= $end) {
   $middle = ($end + $begging) / 2; );
   $line = fread($myfile, $middle);
if(strcmp($line,$indexToSearch) == 0) {
    echo "found";
    break;
}   else
  if(strcmp($line,$indexToSearch) > 0) {
      $end = $middle - 1;
  }  else {
      $begging = $middle + 1;
  }  
}    

 fseek($myfile, $middle);
  echo "<br><br>FINAL: ".fgets($myfile);
```

Comment: Are each of the #indexes on separate lines? If so, do the lines always occur at the beginning of the line? Also, is the index identified by 13 numeric characters? Do the indexes occur within the data as well?

Comment: Indexes are both in the same line.Index is not always identified by 13 numeric characters.No, they are separated by the pipe "|"

Comment: What defines an "index" then? Would *index1, index2, ... index47* be the same thing? Example: `asdf|data|data|data|asdf|data|data|data|asdf|data|data|data`?

Comment: No, index is an unique number

Comment: So, if the indexes don't follow a pattern, how do you define what is an index and what is data? Can you give a better example of the source file?

Comment: index comes with "#" before, so if data beggings with "#" and ends with pipe, I know that its an index

Comment: 1. The function *strcmp* compairs two strings. It does not not look for a string inside of a string. To look for a string inside of another string then you need to use the function *strstr*. 2. The function *fread* reads by chunks (usually 8192 bytes) so depending on the size of your file you may not have half of you file in the *$line* variable. 3. Personally I would use the function *explode* to break the file into an array using '#' as the delimiter, then do the binary search on the array. Am I correct in assuming this is a comp sci project?

Comment: Yes it is a comp sci project. I cannot use memory ram to perform this. Im trying to do this for days. I really need to make this

Comment: When you say you cannot use memory ram to perform this. Are you saying the file is too large to fit into memory at once? What are the exact requirements?

Comment: ... and by the way, you do have the concept correct.

Comment: I just can not use, its in the requirements. But how can I fix it?

Comment: In order for PHP to run, or read any part of the file, it must use RAM. There is a requirement that is misunderstood. If the code you wrote ran as expected, it would at the very least load half of your source file into RAM. I can write something that works, but I am not sure if it fits the requirements.

Comment: I cant just store the hole file into array , but I cant store in variables. If u can write something, please write.. thanks for your helping